# Surface temperature variation with distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, reference-frames, temperature

So here is the question I'm troubling with:

> We estimate that the temperature varies approximatively with that relation:

Comment: One way to solve part "a": in Excel, use Solver to manipulate x and y in order to maximize the value of the function.  Do you know how to use Solver?

Comment: No i need to it myself using derivation etc not using excel or anything like that? I just want any clues how to solve it ..

Comment: Try obtaining the total differential and setting it to zero.  Hopefully, you will have enough equations to uniquely calculate "x" and "y".

Comment: Actually, if you look at the second equation (theta) and we put x=0 and y=0 so we get exp^0.125 = 1.133... So it means we can only get the maximum temperature at this point no?

Comment: Be careful about hidden assumptions.  In other words, can you prove your assumption mathematically?

Comment: hmm i don't know how?

Comment: That's a rhetorical question, but one you must answer before you are sure that you have the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: I mean there are many values possible for the exponential  function so how do I know which one is the maximum?

Comment: Shouldn’t the maximum be where theta is minimum.  This is where the partial derivatives wrt x and y are zero.

Comment: No ? the values of exp^theta can be anywhere from 1 to infinity which is not possible in real life because we can not have such high temperatures

Comment: If someone have the solution for a) that will be very helpfull to solve the rest?

Comment: x = y = 50.  Are you sure of that 3 exponent on D?  It does not seem dimensionally correct.  Shouldn’t it be a 2?

Comment: Correct D^2 not 3.

Comment: Are you sure about that negative sign on theta?

Comment: yes it's negative

Comment: How did you find that at x=y=50 the temperature is maximum?

Comment: Temperature is maximum where theta is minimum.  I found this point by setting the partial derivatives of theta with respect to both x and y equal to zero to find the point, and showed that the second partials were both positive.

Comment: can you put that in the answer section below, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the partial derivative of $\theta$ with respect to both x and y equal to zero yields the following two equations:  $$\frac{5}{4}x+\frac{3}{4}y-100=0$$
$$\frac{5}{4}y+\frac{3}{4}x-100=0$$The solution to these two linear algebraic equations for x and y is $$x=y=50$$The 2nd partial derivatives with respect to both x and y, evaluated at this point, are both positive.  Therefore, the point represents a minimum for $\theta$ and a maximum for T.

Here's a hint for parts b and c:  Use the equation $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+v_x\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=0$$

Comment: so for b and c the answer would be zero because there is no advection right?

Comment: The wind blowing at 30 m/s constitutes advection.

Comment: but it says it's isothermal displacement

Comment: I mean there is advection but there is no changes in local temperature at x = y = -25 km right?

Comment: No.  There is. It is partial T partial t.

Comment: How do I add wind speed in that equation then?

Comment: If I tell you that, it’s the same as my doing the whole problem for you.